# A way to sort new android app updates (not updated by user yet)

Tags: google-play-store, updates, notifications

is there any way to know which apps have new updates (not updated by user yet) by notification date at least.

Because google play notification only mentions you got 2 new update without telling me what apps have new updates.

I have many apps that have new updates that I do not update because I don't want too. So, I want to sort these new updates by notification date or by app release or launch date.

Answer (score 0):

[Change log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thunderclouddev.changelogs) does that. Besides, it also gives out the update info that can help you decide if you want update or not - for instance, I am not interested updating an app which has no value to me, like languages which I never use!

Apps with updates pending are shown *chronologically* with green exclamation mark and on tapping it you get a detailed view of versions and changelog, as shown. Clicking *Update Available* takes to play store

[image]
[image]

> KNOWN BUGS AND LIMITATIONS:( from app description)
>
> - Some applications are missing data. This is controlled by Google's closed-source API and is totally outside of my control.
> - Uninstalled apps aren't removed from the list until the app is restarted.